# how to debug wp7 app in vs2010

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to debug/test wp7 app in vs2010? Can I log any info into a log file? Can I print info on the console? Is there any debug tools for wp7 like android adb?

-Henry

Answer (score 3):

You get an emulator and full debugger integration through Visual Studio. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

Load your project in Visual Studio.  Connect your Phone.  At the top select Windows Phone 7 Device (instead of Emulator).  Press F5.

Now you're debugging.

You can set breakpoints if you want to debug that way, or you can log whatever your want to the output window via Debug.WriteLine().

If you want to log to a file, you can write your own logger that writes data to Isolated Storage.  There is a hacky, non-supported way to get this data off the phone, or you can just add the functionality to your app to view the log.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838261%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). I search about debug and I found it on MSDN page.
Hope it helps.